# How to add files to running jar

Tags: java, file, jar, zip

Here is my code, I am looking for a way to add files to the running jar. Thanks in advance. The error that is occurring presently is "invalid entry size (expected 62 but got 0 bytes). 62 bytes is the size of my MANIFEST file, which gets written. I am uncertain what that has to do with anything.

```
        JarFile replace = new JarFile("newgame.jar");
        JarInputStream jis = null;
        JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                Launcher.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()));
        for (Enumeration<JarEntry> list = replace.entries(); list.hasMoreElements();) {
            JarEntry nextEntry = list.nextElement();
            if (!nextEntry.getName().equals("Launcher.class")) {
                jos.putNextEntry(nextEntry);
                jis = new JarInputStream(replace.getInputStream(nextEntry));
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] byteBuff = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = jis.read(byteBuff)) != -1)
                    out.write(byteBuff, 0, bytesRead);
                jos.write(out.toByteArray());
                out.close();
                jis.close();
            }
        }
        replace.close();
        jos.close();
        new File("newgame.jar").delete();
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Which statement in your code is giving you the error?

Comment: @JimGarrison the jos.putNextEntry(nextEntry); is giving me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with

```
        JarFile replace = new JarFile("newgame.jar");
        InputStream is = null;
        JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                Launcher.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()));
        for (Enumeration<JarEntry> list = replace.entries(); list.hasMoreElements();) {
            JarEntry nextEntry = list.nextElement();
            jos.putNextEntry(nextEntry);
            is = replace.getInputStream(nextEntry);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] byteBuff = new byte[(int) nextEntry.getSize()];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.length)) != -1)
                out.write(byteBuff, 0, bytesRead);
            jos.write(out.toByteArray());
            out.close();
            is.close();
        }
        replace.close();
        jos.close();
        new File("newgame.jar").delete();
```

I converted the JarInputStreams to InputStreams and for some reason this worked.